# Loop won't check multiple if's

Tags: java

My program is supposed to run a formula and print out the end product when a counter reaches 100,200,500,and when a variable hits a certain value. Currently it prints out

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

Which I understand is because before the counter takes effect and bumps up the variable it attempts to divide by zero which causes that. When I do change the variable it stops at 100 and prints out "The value of π at 100 is: 0.0".
Here's the code:

```
int i = 1;
    int counter = 0;
    double pi = 4/((2*i)*(2*i+1)*(2*i+2));
 while(counter <= 100 ){
     i++;
     counter ++;

     if(i==100){
         System.out.println("The value of \u03C0 at 100 is: "+ pi);
     }
     if (i==200){
         System.out.println("The value of \u03C0 at 200 is: " +pi);
     }
     if (i==500){
         System.out.println("The value of \u03C0 at 500 is:"+pi);
     }
     if(pi==3.14159 ){
         System.out.println("The number of iterations to get to 3.14159 is "+counter+". \u03C0 = 3.141599074");
     }
 }
```

Comment: There is nothing in the posted code where `/ by zero` can happen

Comment: Is that complete code? Only division I see is `double pi = 4/((2*i)*(2*i+1)*(2*i+2));` and it doesn't throw `divide by zero exception`?

Comment: You will never reach i == 200 because your while loop stops at 100, and i and counter are incremented at the same rate.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic has some problems. Have you followed your code through with a debugger?  If you look at your code,

```
int i = 1;
    int counter = 0;
    double pi = 4/((2*i)*(2*i+1)*(2*i+2));
```

happens once, before the `while` loop actually changes `i`. Move `pi` into the `while` loop to update `pi` with a new `i`. Debuggers are your friend.

Another place where a debugger would be your friend would be in the `while` loop proper. Follow that through and see what happens when your logic approaches your testing conditionals. Your first excitement I predict will be around `counter = 99` and the next couple of loops through, or not :)

You might want to consider some `if-else` blocks for your multiple tests, or you could also use a `switch` statement for your counter tests.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
...
for (counter = 1; counter <= 500; counter++, i++) {
  double pi = (double) 4/((2*i)*(2*i+1)*(2*i+2));
  if (counter % 100 == 0) {
   System.out.println("The value of \u03C0 at " + counter + " is: "+ pi);
  }

  if(pi == 3.14159 ){
     System.out.println("The number of iterations to get to 3.14159 is "+counter+". \u03C0 = 3.141599074");
 }
}
```